# Режим браузера в IE

Tags: internet-explorer

Как правильно пользоваться переключением режима браузера в IE, если я хочу посмотреть как выглядит верстка в меньших версиях, нужно менять только Режим браузера (IE8/IE7), или также нужно менять Режим документа (IE8/IE7 cоотствественно)?

Comment: Простите за оффтопик, но заголовок «режим браузера в IE» меня повеселил. :)

А если по делу, то, вроде бы, ни одно из двух, вроде бы (не уверен), IE9 в режиме IE7 будет рисовать не как IE7, просто поддерживать некоторые старые глюки. Обычно предлагают ставить несколько версий IE.

Comment: а что тут веселого, если эта опция в инструменте разработчика в ие так и называется - Режим браузера ? да, я знаю, что лучше ставить несколько версий ие, но интересует именно ответ на мой вопрос.

Comment: Вообще правильнее называть это rendering mode, т.е. режим рендеринга.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас начиная с 9 версии есть возможность проссматривать вплоть до 7 версии интернет эксплорер. Нажмите F12(firebug) всплывет консоль найдите **пункт Browser Mode: IE 10** жмите и будет вам выбор более старых версий интернет эксплорера.
У меня Windows 8 поэтому браузер уже 10.

Comment: вы вопрос вообще читали? я спрашиваю, нужно ли при таком просмотре менять только опцию  Режим браузера (IE8/IE7, т.к. у меня IE9) или также нужно менять Режим документа.

Comment: Если бы не читал, то соответсвенно поста бы от меня не было. Значит изъясняться нужно более корректно! Переключать режим документа?! никогда не слышал.Переключайте браузеры и все! Если я вас не правильно понял разъясните.

Comment: Вот так выглядит эта панель переключения в IE9 http://i.imgur.com/BC0WO.png , в опции Режим браузера пункты [IE7 - IE8 - IE9 - Представление совместимости IE9], в опции Режим документа [Режим совместимости - Стандарты IE7 - Стандарты IE8 - Стандарты IE9 (по умолчанию)]. Я и спрашиваю, нужно ли мне менять только Режим браузера, если я хочу посмотреть, как выглядит страница в ие7/ие8, или нужно также менять режим документа на Стандарты ие7/стандарты ие8.

Comment: Спасибо теперь понял. Сколько верстал никогда не переключал режим документа. Перключал только версии браузеров. Мое личное замечание )

Comment: да, я тоже всегда переключаю только режим документа, но тут как раз  возник момент, что при переключении в Режим браузера ИЕ8 страница отображалась нормально, а при переключении еще дополнительно к этому в Режим документа - Стандарты ие8 - верстка уезжала, и так было в настоящем живом ИЕ8. Поэтому и возник вопрос.

Comment: хм... хороший вопрос однако получается! я поспрашиваю конечно, если будет ответ я выложу, если конечно раньше меня не отпишут. Но судя по вашему последнему комменту, так и нужно делать раз это у вас работает(имхо). Подождем более знающего комментария тогда )

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь этим переключение для того, чтобы удостовериться, что js-скрипты верно работают в более старых версия. К примеру, все браузеры нормально понимают объект var a = {class: 1}; кроме ie8 и младше. он говорит, что неверный синтаксис.